# How to put double quotes in excel file around each field?

Tags: excel, csv, coldfusion, cfspreadsheet

I wan to put quotes around each field in my excel file. I have to do this in order to export my excel file to csv. Otherwise if some of my fields contain commas file will get the wrong number of rows and columns. I was looking in `cfspreadsheet` but could not find any solution for this problem. Is there any other way to get this to work in cold fusion? Do I need to loop through the file or some other function can take care of this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it was me, I would start with the easiest method I could think of.  Use cfspreadsheet to read the file.  Then use it again to write a new file in csv format.  If that doesn't work, replace the second step with cffile and a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA solution:

```
Sub DontQuoteMe()
    Dim r As Range, DQ As String

    DQ = Chr(34)
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            r.Value = DQ & r.Value & DQ
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```